# How to get rid of this constraint warning message?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles

I have this layout file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        style="@style/TextViewStyle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Where the `TextViewStyle` style is:

```
<style name="TextViewStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintStart_toStartOf">parent</item>
</style>
```

As you see, the horizontal constraint is set in the styles file and the vertical constraint in the layout file. Although both constraints are set, Android Studio is complaining:

> This view is not constrained horizontally: at runtime it will jump to the left unless you add a horizontal constraint

As in my understanding, it dosn't see the constraint from the styles file. How can I solve this?

Comment: could you not add the constraints to the textview itself. also did you run and see if the constraint's are applied?

Comment: @Raghunandan I just run the project and the constraints are indeed applied but the warning still remains. What do you mean through "not add the constraints to the textview itself"?

Comment: this just a warning i guess its a lint warning. you can ignore or disable it. just google for it.

Comment: @Raghunandan So you say that lint is wrong? Googled it and nothing found. I just found when indeed was a constraint missing.

Comment: no lint is not wrong. it is just how its works. you just disable the lint warning http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code and it works perfectly as it is defined.The lint is only seeing error from the perspective of one file i.e your layout xml , so it shows error. It can be distracting, so suppressing it might be a good idea. But we will have to suppress it in a way that warning for other parts of your xml file don't get effected.

Fortunately android has such a tool.
You can use tools:ignore to suppress any warning from an xml element.
See the android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolsignore).

As the documentation says "This attribute accepts a comma-separated list of lint issue ID's that you'd like the tools to ignore on this element or any of its dependents."

Simply hover over any warning/error etc and press Ctrl+1. You will see the details of the warning you are getting with the 'issue id' at the bottom.
Note this issue id. Then in your xml layout suppress your warning like this:

```
tools:ignore="your error issue id">
```

Note: for using tools you will have to define tools in your xml.

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

For your warning you can use the tools:ignore like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        style="@style/TextViewStyle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And your warning will be gone.